# how to rotate text in python's turtle graphics

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to make diagrams with python's turtle (teaching purposes). The label "values" for the y-axis should be rotated.
Python's turtle has a method to write a string at current position:

```
from turtle import *
left(90) # does not help
write("values", font=('Arial', 12, 'normal'))
hideturtle()
mainloop()
```

"values" is still horizontal.

How can I rotate text with python's turtle?

Comment: Related: [how to upside down a text in python turtle.write() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729657/how-to-upside-down-a-text-in-python-turtle-write-method) and [How to create rotated text in Python's turtle graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72749874/how-to-create-rotated-text-in-pythons-turtle-graphics)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to write rotated text with turtle. See http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/bugs/879806:

> Turtle is built on top of Tk, which is currently at version 8.5 - this has no ability to rotate text. When Tk version 8.6 arrives it should be able to write rotated text (see http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2010-November/002490.html) and turtle.py could be updated to take advantage of it.

Answer (score -1):

You CAN rotate text, but only in Tkinter 8.6. Type:

```
pyturtle.rotate([Degrees of rotation])
```

Then you can do your text command.
Hope this helped!

Comment: What is `pyturtle`? Is that some other module? Can you show a complete example?