# Rotated text in turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I can't seem to get the write function to be rotated. I tried the tilt function. Is there something I'm doing wrong?
I'm thinking it would be something like this:

e.g. If I set some variable to 180 it would turn the text upside down

edit: as requested here is my attempt, I think I'm using tilt wrong, not sure.

the aim is to write the text at a desired angle (in this case 180, or upside down)

```
tilt(180)
write('M', move=False, align="left", font=("Arial", 15, "bold"))
```

still writes it in regular, upright form, as shown here:

[image: failed attempt]

Comment: *I tried the tilt function*. Post your attempts, failures and expected output. In that way you can make your question on-topic for SO (else it will become a [gimmetehcodez] question)

Comment: Hey, take a look at [ask]. It will increase your chances of people answering your question!

Comment: @bhargavrao I've updated the question

Comment: Good that you have updated it. But post an [MCVE]. Include some more bits of code (Dont post the complete code dump).

Comment: As far as I know, `turtle` doesn't have a way of rotating text rendered with the `write()` method. The `tilt()` method only affects the angle of the turtle.

Comment: Related and possible duplicate [how to rotate text in python's turtle graphics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469125/how-to-rotate-text-in-pythons-turtle-graphics)

Comment: @BhargavRao Not a duplicate. I checked that question. It involved an outdated version of turtle/python. It also referred to a function called 'rotate', which I couldn't find in the turtle documentation, and I believe that it may have been the predecessor to 'tilt'.

Comment: What version do you have,  bluesriff? I.e., what does `python -c "import turtle;print(turtle.TK.TkVersion)"` print?

Comment: Interesting that python2 itself is based on 8.6

Comment: @BhargavRao: FWIW, I'm running Python 2.6.6, and my `turtle.TK.TkVersion` is 8.5. So I can't test this **new** `rotate()` method...

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue10531 -> for 3.6+ this issue hasn't been solved.  Glancing through the bug tracker I didn't see a bug logged against 2.6/2.7, but I doubt that it works over there either. Then again, I didn't search all that closely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to rotate text in python's turtle graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469125/how-to-rotate-text-in-pythons-turtle-graphics)