# how to upside down a text in python turtle.write() method?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

nowadays I'm writing a program to fetch 4 poker cards from 52 poker cards randomly and I have to draw these pokers by python turtle module. Now here's my question: cause there's an upside-down number in pokers, [just like this(the bottom right corner number)](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/Cards-5-Diamond.svg)

at first I want to use this code to generate the numbers:

```
import turtle as do
def generate_digital(number, x, y, start_angle, size):
    '''
       this function generate '2-10'
       parameters:
       number: this is number you want to write
       x and y: this is the pen's initial location
       start_angle: the pen's initial direction
       size: the number's size
    '''
    do.penup()
    do.goto(x, y)
    do.pensize(30)
    do.setheading(start_angle)
    do.write(number, font=("Arial", size, "normal"))
```

I want to use 
`do.settheading()` to set the angle of the number, but I found that it didn't work! I can get a 5 but I can't get a upside-down 5 using the do.write() method......

Now, the only way myself can think of is to use this

```
def generate_photo_2(x, y, start_angle, size):
    '''
       this function generate a '2'
       parameters:
       just like last function
    '''
    do.penup()
    do.goto(x, y)
    do.pensize(3)
    do.setheading(start_angle)
    do.pendown()
    do.circle(-size, 200)
    do.fd(2 * size)
    do.left(45)
    do.fd(0.6 * size)
    do.left(90)
    do.fd(2 * size)
```

code to 'draw' a number, and by setting the start angle, I can 'draw' a upside-side number 2, but it causes a lot of trouble, isn't it?

Could anybody tells me how to write() a upside-down number?
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Related: [How to create rotated text in Python's turtle graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72749874/how-to-create-rotated-text-in-pythons-turtle-graphics) and [how to rotate text in python's turtle graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469125/how-to-rotate-text-in-pythons-turtle-graphics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`turtle` doesn't have function to display text upside down.

But `turtle` is built on top of `tkinter` module and `Canvas` widget which has method

```
create_text(x, y, text=.., angle=..., ...)
```

Working example

```
import turtle

c = turtle.getcanvas()

item_id = c.create_text(0, 0, text='5', angle=180, font=("Arial", 30, "normal"))

turtle.mainloop() # run tkinter event loop
```

Later you can change angle using `item_id`

```
c.itemconfig(item_id, angle=45)
```

Effbot.org: [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) in tkinter.

---

**BTW:** I found information that only the newest tkinter with `Tk 8.6` has `angle=`.
You can check version

```
import tkinter 

print(tkinter.TkVersion)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!  This problem disturbed a whole night! And have a nice day:-)