# How to create rotated text in Python's turtle graphics?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am using Python 3.9 with tkinter and tcl version 8.6, so according to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4469264/7711283) here on stackoverflow from the year 2010, I should be able to draw rotated texts. And actually I am able to draw rotated texts in tkinter so I tried to create a rotated text with the turtle module too writing:

```
import turtle
txt = '      '
tt = turtle.Turtle()
tt.write(txt, angle=-45)
```

but got an error message: `TypeError: write() got an unexpected keyword argument 'angle'` which means that the turtle module does not yet support the text rotating feature.

This rises the question: **Do someone know about a patch/fix which enables the turtle module to make use of the text rotation feature available in Python 3 since version 3.7.2 ?**

Comment: Related: [how to upside down a text in python turtle.write() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729657/how-to-upside-down-a-text-in-python-turtle-write-method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have written code of a patch which if added as a header to the turtle Python script allows to use the keyword argument `txt_angle` for creating rotated texts, so that the code:

```
import turtle
txt = '      '
tt = turtle.Turtle()
tt.write(txt, txt_angle=-45)
```

doesn't raise  a TypeError and draws a 45 degree rotated text.

Below the code of the patch followed by a short turtle script code creating attached image out of the rotated text:

[image: turtle rotated text star]

```
class Patch_txt_angle:
    def RawTurtleDOTwrite(self, arg, move=False, align="left", font=("Arial", 11, "normal"), txt_angle=0):
        if self.undobuffer:
            self.undobuffer.push(["seq"])
            self.undobuffer.cumulate = True
        end = self._write(str(arg), align.lower(), font, txt_angle)
        if move: x, y = self.pos() ; self.setpos(end, y)
        if self.undobuffer: self.undobuffer.cumulate = False
    def RawTurtleDOT_write(self, txt, align, font, txt_angle):
        item, end = self.screen._write(self._position, txt, align, font, self._pencolor, txt_angle)
        self.items.append(item)
        if self.undobuffer: self.undobuffer.push(("wri", item))
        return end
    def TurtleScreenBaseDOT_write(self, pos, txt, align, font, pencolor, txt_angle):
        x, y = pos ; x = x * self.xscale ; y = y * self.yscale
        anchor = {"left":"sw", "center":"s", "right":"se" }
        item = self.cv.create_text(x-1, -y, text = txt, anchor = anchor[align],
            fill = pencolor, font = font, angle = txt_angle)
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = self.cv.bbox(item)
        self.cv.update()
        return item, x1-1
import turtle
turtle.RawTurtle.write         = Patch_txt_angle.RawTurtleDOTwrite
turtle.RawTurtle._write        = Patch_txt_angle.RawTurtleDOT_write
turtle.TurtleScreenBase._write = Patch_txt_angle.TurtleScreenBaseDOT_write
# ======================================================================
txt = '      '
tt = turtle.Turtle()
sc = turtle.Screen() ; sc.bgcolor("black")
for enum_index, txt_angle in enumerate(range(0, 36000, 1125)):
    if (enum_index)%4 == 0: tt.color("green" ); fontsize=10
    if (enum_index)%4 == 1: tt.color("yellow"); fontsize=15
    if (enum_index)%4 == 2: tt.color("red"   ); fontsize=10
    if (enum_index)%4 == 3: tt.color("orange"); fontsize=13
    txt_angle /= 100    
    tt.setheading(txt_angle); tt.forward(100)
    tt.write(txt, font=("Arial", fontsize, "bold"), align="right", txt_angle=txt_angle)
    tt.backward(100)
from time import sleep; sleep(30)
```